# How can I use ffmpeg to split MPEG video into 2 gb chunks?

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to split a larger video into bits that are a specific or equal size so that I may upload them to a file sharing site. I know you can split videos like this by time,

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:20:00 -f segment output%03d.mp4`

However, I feel it would be easier to split them by file size to each be exactly 2bg. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You can't split **exactly** by size and still get a playable video segment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split by size, the [`split`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) tool will be a better fit for the job. You can set the block size by using `split -b 2G video.mp4`, and it will generate files named `xaa`, `xab`, etc. To combine them again to create the mp4, use a glob like `cat xa? > video.mp4`. If you have other files which start with 'xa' or whatever, you can change the default prefix it uses.

Comment: I'd suggest that each video would need to be playable - in which case `split` wouldn't work.

Comment: that's true, I got the impression that he just wanted to bypass some sort of size limit on a file-sharing service, and would be downloading them to deal with later.